# Fourier series - Why does $\hat f(0) \ne 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Let $f\in C^1$, $2\pi$-periodic, and let's assume $\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f'|^2 \le 1$. Prove:
>
> 1. $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} |\hat f(n)|^2 \le \frac{1}{2\pi}$$
> 2. There's a $c\in\mathbb{C}$ such that: $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f-c|^2 \lt 1$$

Now, I already proved #1 by using Parsevals' Theorem.
I know that the answer for #2 is $c = \hat f(0)$.

consider the function $g = f-c$. Then,

$$\hat g(n) = \hat {f-c}(n) = \hat f(n) - \hat c(n)$$

Now, for $n\ne 0$, $\hat g(n) = \hat f(n)$ but for $n=0$, $\hat g(n) = 0$.

If $\hat f(0) \ne 0$.

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f-c|^2 = 2\pi \|f-c\|^2 = 2\pi \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f-c}(n)|^2 \lt \sum_{0 \ne n\in\mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f-c}(n)|^2 \le \frac{1}{2\pi}2\pi = 1$$

BUT! can we tell for sure that $\hat f(0) \ne 0$? How?

Comment: We might have $\hat{f}(0) = 0$. But $0\in \mathbb{C}$, so that's no problem.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I've fixed #2. It must be "less than". That's my problem...

Comment: So if $\hat f(0) = 0$ we might get an equality. aren't  we? And that's not good enough.

Comment: Well, take a look at $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ix}$, that's a pretty simple function.

Comment: yeah, it's a simple one - we have $\hat f(1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}$ and for $n\ne 1$ we have $\hat f(n) = 0$. again, we have $\le$ but not $\lt$.

Comment: And that shows that without additional hypotheses, we cannot deduce the existence of a $c$ such that the strict inequality holds.

Comment: I see. By the way, for a "week inequality we could just pick $c=0$.aren't we? It  seems to me like an overhead picking $\hat f(0)$